# How to pass data from Vue to Laravel for patch request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, http-patch

i'm trying to send a patch request from my Vuetify data-table to Laravel & then to a mySQL DB.

Here's various code pieces from my controller.php, my api.php & the actual Vuetify file:

api.php:

```
Route::patch('machines/{id}', [
    'as'   => 'machines/{id}',
    'uses' => 'MachineController@update'
]);
```

MachineController.php

```
$machines = Machine::find($request->id)->update();
```

the actual axios patch req. in the .vue file:

```
Object.assign(this.machines[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem);

axios.patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id, {
    editedItem: this.editedItem
})
```

In the Telescope payload section i'm getting the updated object, but i'm also getting a message:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: 
>   Integrity constraint violation:
>   1048 Column cannot be null.

For all the columns.

I have also tried this syntax for a patch method:

```
if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
    Object.assign(this.machines[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem);
    axios
        .patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id)
        .then(res => {
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.editedItem);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
} else {
    this.machines.push(this.editedItem);
}
this.close();
```

And i tried setting up the controller like this:

```
$machines = Machine::find($request->id);
$machines->machine_number = $request->input('machine_number');
$machines->machine_name = $request->input('machine_name');
$machines->machine_company = $request->input('machine_company');
$machines->machine_division = $request->input('machine_division');
$machines->machine_center = $request->input('machine_center');
$machines->machine_speed = $request->input('machine_speed');
$machines->save();
```

But I'm still getting the same error.
Can someone help me out, or at least point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you `dd($request->all())` to see if anything is being passed through?

Comment: @thisiskelvin I just did, and nothing happened. Nothing showed anywhere, nothing changed ;/. Not quite: when i added ```dd($request->all());``` to the controller, Telescope stopped registering the patch request.

Comment: Are you against using `post` instead of `patch`? Not that this is the solution.

Comment: @thisiskelvin From my understanding, in order to update selected fields from a table, you should use patch req. I might be wrong tho.

Comment: Not necessarily, passing an `id` visually signifies an `update`. Without, it should be assumed you are trying to `store` a new record.

Comment: Okay, i'll give it a shot by using ```post```, but what bothers me is that apparently the data is somehow lost between the vue & controller (i'm logging it once i send the ```patch``` req. and it's there, it's in the Telescope payload, but it doesn't reach the DB.

Comment: Thats the part Im concerned with. This could be an axios issue. Best way to test is to change from `patch` to `post` and see if all works as intended.

Comment: @thisiskelvin I changed the methods from ```patch``` to ```post``` both in the axios req. & the controller, but it behaves the same as before.
I'm relatively new to Laravel & mySQL connecting to Vue, is there any more information i can provide that will help in solving the issue ?

Comment: Are you using the code with contains the `this.close()` statement? If so, you're `patch` method doesnt have data passed in as the second argument.

Comment: @thisiskelvin This is the code in the `this.close()` method:

`
    close() {
      this.dialog = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = this.editedItem;
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      }, 300);
    }
`
However, i've commented it out and i'm just calling 
`
this.dialog = false;
`
to close the dialog window when i save

Comment: @thisiskelvin I removed both the `this.close()` method & the `this.dialog = false;`,
but it didn't help. ;/

Comment: More so talking about adding the data to the `patch` method, at the moment its only `.patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id)`, but should be `.patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id, { ... })`

Comment: @thisiskelvin Here's how my `patch` method looks:

`  
    axios
        .patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id, {
          editedItem: this.editedItem
        })
`
I believe i'm passing the data after the id ?
My idea is that the editedItem is an object, and this.editedItem is an object as well, so that's why i'm passing it like this. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @thisiskelvin I have structured my `patch` request like this, same result:
`axios
        .patch("machines/" + this.editedItem.id, {
          id: this.editedItem.id,
          machine_number: this.editedItem.machine_number,
          machine_name: this.editedItem.machine_name,
          machine_company: this.editedItem.machine_company,
          machine_division: this.editedItem.machine_division,
          machine_center: this.editedItem.machine_center,
          machine_speed: this.editedItem.machine_speed
        })
`
*Also tried it with `post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue: I was passing empty object with my `axios.patch()` request because i've set it up wrong. I've changed the object's structure to `key:value` pairs and voila, it worked!